Create a New Plugin
I need to create a new plugin and publish it as a standalone module. Could you please share the steps to accomplish this? There is no way mentioned in the documentation where it is mentioned that how we can create the new plugin and where to publish that plugin.
Thank you in advance for your assistance!
